# Functions satisfying $\int_0^1\cos(\pi x)f(x) = \int_0^1\sin(\pi x )f(x) = 0$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Are there any continuous, nonzero functions that satisfy:
$$
\int_0^1\cos(\pi y)f(y)\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^1\sin(\pi y )f(y) \mathrm{d}y = 0
$$
?

For reference: I am trying to find the kernel of the integral kernel given by $\sin(\pi(x-y))$ where integration is done with respect to $y$. Can we completely characterize this space somehow (I.e some closed form representation?)

Comment: Given any $N$ functions $f_1,\dots, f_N$, the space of.all $f$ such that $\int f_i (x) f(x) dx =0$ for all $i$ is infinite dimensional. In particular, there is such a function.

Answer (score 2):

$f(y)=\sin (3\pi y)$ is one such function.

Comment: The two functions $\sin(\pi x)$ and $\cos(\pi x)$ are part of a well-known orthogonal basis (which  you learn when you study "Fourier series").  So (as Kavi did) you can take any other function from that orthogonal basis, and of course it will be orthogonal to these two.

Comment: @GEdgar does this have to do with the fact that $\{e^{in \theta}\}$ forms an orthonormal basis for $L^2$ ?